# Footer going under a DIV

Tags: html, css, forms, jquery, styling

I have a form that is being submitted using AJAX. When the form submits it changes to display:none and a div with the success message shows in its place.

I am unsure how to prevent this. I know its CSS related. Here is the CSS for that div

```
#ajaxform{
    position:relative;
z-index:1
}

#ajaxdiv{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    width:650px;
    background-color:#f3f3f3;
    z-index:10;
}
```

What would you guys recommend trying so the overlap does not happen.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your `#ajaxdiv` has `position:absolute`. If you remove the absolute positioning then that should solve your problem, although you probably have absolute positioning on the element for a reason, in which case it might just create new problems!

Comment: Thanks, I had the absolute positioning for something I was testing at one point but did not use it so I changed it =>

Comment: Glad to be able to help. That's a nice looking form.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `#ajaxdiv` to `position:relative;`

Also quick FYI: Don't use `<br />` tags to position content. Break tags should be used to specify a break in text where you want to manually break a line of text. For positioning use padding or margin. Im referring to the two `<br />` tags you have above the `#ajaxdiv` container

Comment: Thanks for the info on the br tags. I forgot to go back and assign some CSS in place of breaks. It should be done now though => One side note the place I had to do this was the "artist" section where I am using the jquery cycle plugin. Why did it kick the document under the header when using the cycle. It did not do that before.

Answer (score 1):

You have a div

If you add min-height:100px, then it seems showing without clipping.

```
<div class="box_fullwidth" style="min-height:100px">
```

I just signed up and played with the div code.

I also removed the 2 line breaks